# Swift 2.0 Today extension issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, today-extension

I have a project that I have been working on for a couple of months. Everything worked fine until I updated Xcode from 6.x to 7.1 and Swift from 1.x to 2.1. The issues I have now is the following:

- When I run the today widget viewDidAppear is only called sometimes (maybe 1 of 5 times), it happens sometimes on a simulator but almost everytime on an actual device
- I can only debug (breakpoints and logs) sometimes to, maybe 1 of 5 times, it´s the same on a simulator and on an actual device

I´m not really sure why. I have created a new project but it´s the same there. I have pasted the code below for the test project. Regarding the debugging I have done this: Xcode > Debug > Attach to process by PID or Name > Added my .com... But it´s still the same.

The major differences between the project before I updated and now is:

- I´m using a Realm.io db and not a sqlite db

But this shall not affect since I´m having the same problem with my test project. So the issues here is when I run the Today widget (open it), Hello World shall count up and when I close the today widget and re-open it the counter shall be 0 and start count up again, but it gets stuck on the value that I had when I closed the today extension and when I open it again viewDidAppear is not called as it should. By closing I mean I drag the today extension up/presses the home button.

Appreciate help.

The code for my test project:

```
import UIKit
import NotificationCenter

class TodayViewController: UIViewController, NCWidgetProviding {
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var lblText: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("viewDidLoad")
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidAppear")
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: Selector("getData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidDisappear")
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)) {
        // Perform any setup necessary in order to update the view.

        // If an error is encountered, use NCUpdateResult.Failed
        // If there's no update required, use NCUpdateResult.NoData
        // If there's an update, use NCUpdateResult.NewData

        completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
    }

    func getData(){
        print("getData")
        counter+=1
        lblText.text = "Hello World \(counter)"
    }

}
```

Update:
Saw that I had missed some with the following but have updated them, but it´s the same behavior.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewDidLoad")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("viewDidAppear")
        print(counter)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("viewWillAppear")
        counter = 0
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.0, target: self, selector: Selector("getData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        print("viewDidDisappear")
        timer.invalidate()
    }
```

Comment: Did you convert your project to Swift 2? Are any extra frameworks or libraries you're using not in Swift 2? If so this may be a problem.

Comment: Yes I have converted my project to Swift 2 and I'm only using Realm. In my test project I haven't added Realm and it's a Swift 2 project.

Comment: Hi Have you tried to delete the projects on the devices (both the physical one and the simulator) I have had strange behaviour also, which vanished as soon as I did a reinstall.

Comment: @user1700737 yes I have. I did reset the content and settings on the simulator and removed the application on the phone and reinstalled.

Comment: Ahh, why are you calling  super.viewWillAppear(animated) from viewDidAppear?

Comment: I've noticed something similar in my own project (with Xcode 7.1.1, iOS 9.1), where viewDidAppear isn't called until you dismiss the today/notification center panel... very strange. However, viewWillAppear is called when you view the today extension - so I've moved my data retrieval code there.  (as well as within the widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler method).